# Set the "Treat labels as text" value to true for a Google spreadsheet chart via a script

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am writing a script within the Google Spreadsheet Apps Script interface and I want to flag the marker for 'Treat labels as text' as true.

There is nothing in the App Script documentation that specifically mentions this marker so the closest I can figure is it may be possible via this method:

```
setOption(option, value)
```

It seems to be a catch-all for setting values that don't otherwise have their own method but I have no idea what values to pass to access that specific option; very frustrating.  Here are direct links to the documentation:

- [setOption method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/line-chart-builder#setoptionoption-value)
- [Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts#properties)
- [Line Chart Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/line-chart-builder)

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of old, but maybe it is still relevant for someone. For me the following seems to do the job:

```
.setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything can be parsed as a number, gets converted into the number. Moreover, if you add a space, it's get trimmed.

The solution which worked for me was to prepend an apostrophe or insert a **no-break space** to every label cell.

`"'" + number`

`"\u00A0" + number`

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be such an option on EmbeddedCharts, nevertheless you get the result by setting the format of the label cells to *plain text*.

```
var labelRange = mySheet.getRange("A1:A10"); // range of the label cells
labelRange.setNumberFormat("@");
```